# Error ("Subscript Out Of Range"?) on ReDim Preserve

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I've gotten some great help on here, but I can't seem to use all my newfound knowledge to figure out the error in this bit of code. Anyone?

```
Sub build_StringLists()
Dim rw As Long, v As Long, vTMP As Variant, vSTRs() As Variant
Dim bReversedOrder As Boolean, dDeleteSourceRows As Boolean
ReDim vSTRs(0)

bReversedOrder = False
dDeleteSourceRows = True

With ActiveSheet
    For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, "D")) Then
            ReDim Preserve vSTRs(0 To UBound(vSTRs) - 1)
            If Not bReversedOrder Then
                For v = LBound(vSTRs) To UBound(vSTRs) / 2
                    vTMP = vSTRs(UBound(vSTRs) - v)
                    vSTRs(UBound(vSTRs) - v) = vSTRs(v)
                    vSTRs(v) = vTMP
                Next v
            End If
            .Cells(rw, "D") = Join(vSTRs, ", ")
            .Cells(rw, "D").Font.Color = vbBlue
            If dDeleteSourceRows Then _
                .Cells(rw, "D").Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(vSTRs) + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            ReDim vSTRs(0)
        Else
            vSTRs(UBound(vSTRs)) = .Cells(rw, "D").Value2
            ReDim Preserve vSTRs(0 To UBound(vSTRs) + 1)
        End If
    Next rw
End With

End Sub
```

I am getting "subscript out of range" as an error, consistently. This code should be pulling data from cells D2-D39998, and concatenating it, followed by deleting the now-empty rows.

**Edited to add an example what the script should be doing**

[image]

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code to identify the **specific** line that is causing the exception to be raised. *Subscript out of range* means that you're reading past the end (or before the start) of an array, so when you find that line examine the values of the index you're using into the array and check the array itself to make sure it's the size you think.

Comment: `vSTRs()` starts out with zero elements, then you try to do `ReDim Preserve vSTRs(0 To UBound(vSTRs) - 1)` You can't make an array with negative elements.

Comment: @Kyle Awesome! I think that's it! So what is the best fix to that? I am not an experienced coder in VBA, clearly. Setting vSTRs to 1?

Comment: @kyle - For what you say to happen, it would have to be on the first cycle of the For ... Next loop. It cannot be in the first cycle because by definition, the first cycle lands on a populated cell.

Comment: Are you certain the cell is populated? Put a breakpoint on the `If IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, "D")) Then` line and see which row `RW` is on and check it manually just to be certain. Perhaps you starting the loop one row higher than you anticipate (or something)

Comment: And, as @kenwhite said, you should be able to very quickly tell which line is causing the problem when the error is shown. Hit the "DEBUG" button on the popup window and see which line is highlighted. That's super critical for debugging in VBA.

Comment: I believe the problem is that there may be two blank cells in a row. That could cause the error but it would have completed at least one concatenation cycle by then and that should have been noted. From all provided sample data, the possibility of two blank cells in a row was never put forward; in fact, quite possibly the opposite. A check to see that `UBound(vSTRs) > 0` could be made before entering the 'paste-back-to-worksheet' section. However, this also opens the question -*'What to do with the extra blank cell?'*

Comment: @Jeeped I think you're right. I edited the original post to show a better screenshot of what needs to happen. The empty cells may be the issue. So it would then need to leave the empty rows intact (it could check for data in column C, and if there is data, leave that row alone). Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have two consecutive blank cells somewhere in the list and want to skip processing the extra blank cell (row), then this check should fix that situation.

```
With ActiveSheet
    For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, "D")) Then
            If UBound(vSTRs) > 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve vSTRs(0 To UBound(vSTRs) - 1)
                If Not bReversedOrder Then
                    For v = LBound(vSTRs) To UBound(vSTRs) / 2
                        vTMP = vSTRs(UBound(vSTRs) - v)
                        vSTRs(UBound(vSTRs) - v) = vSTRs(v)
                        vSTRs(v) = vTMP
                    Next v
                End If
                .Cells(rw, "D") = Join(vSTRs, ", ")
                .Cells(rw, "D").Font.Color = vbBlue
                If dDeleteSourceRows Then _
                    .Cells(rw, "D").Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(vSTRs) + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                ReDim vSTRs(0)
            End If
        Else
            vSTRs(UBound(vSTRs)) = .Cells(rw, "D").Value2
            ReDim Preserve vSTRs(0 To UBound(vSTRs) + 1)
        End If
    Next rw
End With
```

Comment: I modified the original post to show that there are some blank cells in column D, which should remain intact. The script could check column C, and if there is data there and no data below that line in column D, leave that row alone. Does that make sense? Thanks for your help here, and patience with a newbie :)